# VSC -> Git -> Annotate button is disabled

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a git project in IDEA. And sometimes `Git` -> `Annotate` button becomes disabled. It was disabled almost all the time and enabled only when IDEA is just started, or project is just reindexed.

First I thought that it could be memory issues, but even after I set `Xms` and `Xmx` options to 8G in the idea.Vmoptions, `Annotate` was still disabled.

Do you have any ideas what can be the reason for such behavior? And how is it possible to fix it?
Thank you!

p.s. Git setup for the project is correct. It's possible to commit/pull/push etc.

**UPD** these files are not ignored, they are not under git submodules, they are versioned `.java.' files

**UPD2** IDEA logs are empty, and command-line `git` equivalent works fine for those files

**UPD3** OK, after I click `Refresh` in Version Control tool window, `Annotate` button becomes active. But I do some changes - it becomes disabled again.

**UPD4** Ok, the question can be summarized as: is there a way for IDEA to refresh my local changes automatically? `Settings` -> `Version Control` -> `Background` -> `Refresh changes every...` doesn't refresh local changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm [`git annotate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate) is active in IntelliJ (2016.2.4) for any versioned files (not folder or project itself)

You can also [activate it through the file gutter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-annotations.html)

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/annotateShow.png]

---

For the files where Annotate is inactive, you can check if the command-line equivalent of Annotate does work.
See [issue 161433](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161433):

```
git -c core.quotepath=false blame --porcelain -l -t -w %revision_hash% -- %file_name%
```

Check also the message view for any error, as in [issue 160309](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160309)

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847035/vsc-git-annotate-button-is-disabled/39847256#comment78145093_39847256) by the [OP esin88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553934/esin88)

> **The problem was that my whole project folder was ignored**, but in `Preferences | Version Control | Ignored Files`, not in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm talking about versioned files. And I know this feature.

Comment: @esin88 yes, I confirm I see annotate active on any versioned files in my Git repos.

Comment: @esin88 What OS and IntelliJ version are you using?

Comment: How can it be, that for versioned files this `Annotate` option is disabled? But sometimes enabled. Maybe `git` plugin is trying to fetch history and disables this option for some time?

Comment: @esin88 maybe those files are part of a submodule? (check for.gitmodules file near to root folder of your Git repo)

Comment: it's latest IDEA: IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
And Mac OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6)

Comment: @esin88 are those files ignored? (check for a .gitignore)

Comment: no :) I tell you, sometimes this `Annotate` button is enabled, and I can watch git history for these files. But sometimes it becomes disabled (for the same files) and I can't figure out why

Comment: @esin88 I sue the same IntelliJ with java files... but on Windows 7. I never experienced that.

Comment: @esin88 do you have error messages as in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160309?

Comment: Nope, IDEA logs are empty, and command-line equivalent works fine for those files.

Comment: The problem was that my whole project folder was ignored, but in `Preferences | Version Control | Ignored Files` not in `.gitignore`.

Comment: @esin88 Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Your VCS is not enabled, hence the issue. Below is the solution for that:

1. Click on the VCS option in the menu bar
2. Enable VCS
3. Select your version control
4. Done, you should be able to use the annotate option

Comment: A downvote without a reason is not helpful to anyone, these steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing in Version Control tool window did't work for me. So I just created a new project, re-imported the module, then the annotate command was enabled both in the file gutter and in the menu.

Hope this helps.